# Django Pass file from one view action to another

Tags: python, django

I have a view with two actions.
First one renders FileInput for csv. After submit, I read csv header and render the template for second action with dropdown containing header items. 
After dropdown items are selected and submitted, I want to read csv file, saving selected columns to db in second action.
How can I pass file from one action to another?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. The solution here is to store the file somewhere and save the file path in session, then read the path back from session and re-read the file.

Also, having the same view doing so many things is possibly not the best design, but YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

pickle the file and store the pickle details in session from the view and access the pickle details from session in another view .